# Javascript : Dedup 2 dimensional array by single column

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a 2 dimensional array of Sales ID and Customer ID

```
[['S01','C01'], ['S01', 'C02'], ['S02', 'CO3'], ['SO4','CO4']]
```

I would like to remove duplicate entries by Sales ID alone. Expected output :

```
[['S01','C01'], ['S02', 'CO3'], ['SO4','CO4']]
```

Since the array is huge, what is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: do you want to keep only the first duplicate?

Comment: @NinaScholz - expected output is provided

Comment: @NinaScholz, yes first record should be retained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for keeping track of seen keys and filter the array.

```js
const
    data = [['S01','C01'], ['S01', 'C02'], ['S02', 'CO3'], ['SO4','CO4']],
    seen = {},
    result = data.filter(([key]) => !seen[key] && (seen[key] = true));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) wrapped in a closure.

```js
const
    data = [['S01','C01'], ['S01', 'C02'], ['S02', 'CO3'], ['SO4','CO4']],
    result = data.filter((seen => ([v]) => !seen.has(v) && seen.add(v))(new Set));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `filter` method and store seen ids this which you can set to object as a last param to filter.

```js
const data = [['S01','C01'], ['S01', 'C02'], ['S02', 'CO3'], ['SO4','CO4']]

const result = data.filter(function([id]) {
  if (!this[id]) return this[id] = 1;
  else return false
}, {})

console.log(result)
```