# How to remove duplicates of a multi-dimensional array based on a column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How to remove duplicates of a multi-dimensional array based on a column

I can do this for a two-dimensional array if the column to dedup on is column A/Header1

But how to do this if I want to dedup on column B/Header2

Or, more generally, if I have a M x N array, how to dedup on any column `p`

from here
[Javascript : Dedup 2 dimensional array by single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64504660/javascript-dedup-2-dimensional-array-by-single-column)

```
function ABC(){

  const
    data = [
            ['Header1','Header2']
            ['S01','C01'], 
            ['S01', 'C02'], 
            ['S02', 'CO3'], 
            ['SO4','CO4']
           ],
    seen = {},
    result = data.filter(([key]) => !seen[key] && (seen[key] = true)); 

  console.log(result);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For case of filtering 2D array, where duplicates are not on the first place (not in first column for data collected from some range), you can try this way...

```
const accu = [];    ///// Array for collecting first appearance of the value
const data = [['S01','C01', 'D01'], ['S01', 'C02', 'D01'], ['S02', 'CO3', 'D02'], ['SO4','CO4', 'D03']];       ////// JUST AN EXAMPLE
const col = 2;    ////////////////////  ENTER HERE THE NUMBER OF THE COLUMN - 1

function filterDuplicates(){
  var output = data.filter(helper);
  console.log(output);
}

function helper(ar){
  var res = true;
  if(accu.indexOf(ar[col]) > -1){
    res = false;
  }
  else {
    accu.push(ar[col]);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Just set the number of the column to be decreased by one, ie 3rd column (or third element in the 1D array) will need to be const col = 2;